# Why is this differential equation linear?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I came across a question asking whether the following ODE is linear or not, and the solutions said that it is linear but I don't understand why:

$\frac{y'}{(y-3)}=-\frac{x}{2}$

For an ODE to be linear, you can't have any products of variables, so if you multiplied both sides by $(y-3)$, you get a product of $x$ and $y$?

Any help would be much appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Not sure about the question but $(\ln(y-3))'=\frac{y'}{y-3}$ this might be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to check your definition again. A first-order ODE is called linear if it is of the form
$$a(x)y + b(x)y' + c(x) = 0.$$
Here, $a$, $b$ and $c$ need not be linear. In other words, the ODE only needs to be linear in $y$ to be called linear.

Answer (score 2):

The standard definition of a linear ODE is an equation of the form:

$a_0(x)y+a_1(x)y'+a_2(x)y''+...+a_n(x)y^{(n)}+b(x)=0$

Your equation indeed has that form. You can have a product of the form $xy$, it is ok. What you can't have is products like $yy'$.